# Why is my hash getting flattened?

Tags: perl, hash, reference, dereference

I am passing an array of references by reference to a subroutine. When I try to deference it in a sub-routine, it gives a flattened hash. How can I fix this? I don't want to have a flat hash and I am unable determine the reason for this.

I am sure that I am making a mistake somewhere but not able to spot it. Any comments/suggestions are totally welcome! Looking forward to hear from this wonderful community! Thanks in advance.

***updated problem statement:***
Basically I am looking to pass a hash by reference to a sub-routine. And my issue is that when I accept it in the subroutine with a scalar variable, and then I try to de-reference it with % symbol, I still get a flat hash.

***update:*** There was a confusion.As I was checking whether my hash is flat or not - I checked only with `print Dumper %hash` when I should actually have actually checked with `print Dumper \%hash`. Lack of this piece of information caused this issue.

**Script:**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict ;
use warnings ;
use Data::Dumper ;

my %h = (moe => "joe", toe => "poe") ;
my @a = (1,2,3,4) ;

my @refs = \(%h,@a) ;

sub sample()
{
  my $ref = shift ;
  my @refs = @{$ref} ;
  print "What I got in the sub! Seems OK!!\n" ;
  print Dumper @refs, "\n" ;

  my %h = %{$refs[0]} ;
  my @a = @{$refs[1]} ;

  print "I am not able to dereference this :(. Please help!! Hash is flat :(\n" ;
  print Dumper %h ;
  print Dumper @a ;
}

&sample(\@refs) ;
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
23:34:17[Host@User]$ ./test.pl 
What I got in the sub! Seems OK!!
$VAR1 = {
          'moe' => 'joe',
          'toe' => 'poe'
        };
$VAR2 = [
          1,
          2,
          3,
          4
        ];
$VAR3 = '
';
I am not able to dereference this :(. Please help!! Hash is flat :(
$VAR1 = 'moe';
$VAR2 = 'joe';
$VAR3 = 'toe';
$VAR4 = 'poe';
$VAR1 = 1;
$VAR2 = 2;
$VAR3 = 3;
$VAR4 = 4;
```

Comment: You may like Data::Printer. If it's about inspecting data structures, it will be a lot easier to work with than Data::Dumper, which is for machine consumption.

Comment: You have made things very complicated for yourself. You have a remarkable number of references and dereferences, and you are misusing subroutine prototypes and defeating them by calling with `&`. I can only imagine that this has been written as a "find all the errors" homework task. That would be fine, but please say so in your question.

Comment: @simbabque: I've never understood the appeal of `Data::Printer`, can you explain? I've always preferred the output of `Data::Dump` to that of `Data::Dumper`, but only because its default output is more concise. There is also the option of `JSON` and `YAML`, and I don't see why yet another unparseable format is better than any of those.

Comment: @Borodin I like it because it sorts hash keys, shows everything neatly and concisely, knows about class internals, inheritance, lists methods, and it's in color! I learned "debugging" with Data::Dumper and used it for a long time. I just feel that for when I have to read it, `p` is nicer. Maybe it's a preference, I'm not sure. But the other ones you mentioned are all for transferring data. DDP is for you reading it quickly, and only for that.

Comment: @simbabque: Ah, of course, I forgot the colour! But have you tried [`Data::Dump`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dump)? It's called as `dd` and produces parseable Perl. (Hashes are sorted.) It's written by the wonderful **Gisle Aas** who authored `LWP`. I feel that Perl is as easy as anything to read, having worked with it all day long!

Comment: @Borodin yes, I used to use it for maybe a year before I switched to DDP. I still use it in production code when I need to create diffable dumps of data structures, like database fixtures. It also sorts data, which is very useful for that. But I see it as a serializer more than a debugging aid.

Comment: @simbabque: We'll have to differ! But I can't imagine using either `Data::Dump` or `Data::Dumper` for serialisation. Of course **Sinan** prefers to debug with YAML so we have the full set!

Comment: @Borodin as long as we don't need to put `<pre>` around it I'm good with most if them. Whatever is available and gets the job done. :-)

Comment: @Borodin I didn't come here to make someone do homework. That was not my intention. However, if that is what it looks like - kindly pardon me and I hope that I don't give that kind of impression next time. Speaking of '&', I have mixed information on the prototyping - some suggest its bad and some otherwise. Need to look into more deeply. Thank you for time and efforts.

Comment: @User9102d82: Let me be clear. Asking for help with homework is fine, but it is important that you say so as it should generate a very different sort of answer. I'm still unclear whether your problem is a homework question or not; I was simply saying that the extreme nature of the code made it look like a "find all the errors" problem. With regard to subroutine prototypes, you shouldn't use them as a matter of course. They have a very specific purpose, described in **chromatic's** excellent [*Modern Perl*](http://modernperlbooks.com/mt/2009/08/the-problem-with-prototypes.html)

Comment: @Borodin I appreciate your kind words to guide me to seek help and guidance the right way but some times that is how a problem can be like. They are problems because one is unaware of how is is suppose to work and is unable to gather further information to help oneself. Thus one may end up making wrong assumptions and I believe that it causes a problem to come to life in the first place.

It would have been more useful to me and to the whole SO community, had you elaborated on the "extremeness" nature of the code instead of   labelling it, given your extreme (111,344) point reputation - Sir.

Comment: @User9102d82: I don't see what my reputation points have to do with this, and I don't see why you want me to go ahead and write an entirely inappropriate answer for a question about a homework assignment. It would be much more useful if you just *answered* my question in the first place. (Or does your low (447) point reputation prevent you from doing so?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing to fix. You have what you wanted. You have a hash in `%h` and an array in `@a`.

But `Data::Dumper` takes a list of arguments and it treats each of its arguments as a separate variable to dump. So when you pass either a hash or an array to `Dumper()`, they will be unrolled into a list and you'll get them displayed as separate variables.

If you want to see the structure of an array or a hash using `Dumper()`, you should pass in a reference to the data structure instead.

```
print Dumper \%h;
print Dumper \@a;
```

Of course, that's effectively what you're doing on your first call to `Dumper()`.

```
print Dumper @refs;
```

I should also point out that you have a couple of errors in your code that (fortunately?) cancel each other out. You define your subroutine `sample` with an empty prototype (`sample() { ... }`) which means that you will get a fatal error if you pass it any arguments. But when you call the subroutine, you use an `&` (`&sample(@refs)`) and one of the effects of that is to turn off prototype checking - so it works even though you pass arguments to the subroutine.

Best to omit the prototype completely (`sub sample { ... }`) and call the subroutine without the ampersand (`sample(@refs))`).

Comment: Hi, my reason for not using prototype, as I mentioned - I have read mixed information on that so I am still unclear and looking for better explanations.

I use the & symbol so that I don't get the warning (when use warnings is in use) that sub has been called early.

Comment: Thanks. I accept your explanation as solution/answer.

Comment: @User9102d82: Ask any Perl expert if you should be using prototypes and you will get the answer "no". There are a small number of good reasons to use them, but none of them are applicable to simple code like yours. Buy my point is that you are using them wrongly. You are declaring a subroutine with an empty prototype (which means "this subroutine has no parameters") but you want to pass parameters to the subroutine. That's your biggest problem here.

Comment: @User9102d82: And you won't get an error about calling subroutine too early as long as you put parentheses on the call. A call like `sample(@refs)` will always work fine and looks more recognisable to non-Perl programmers than `&sample(@refs)`. Also, putting the ampersand on the call **turns off prototype checking** which seems a silly thing to do if you're using prototypes.